# How can one prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1 +\frac k n)^n = e^k$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-writing, exponential-function

The equality in question is widely used to solve for limits like $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n+1}{n-2}$, but how do you actually prove that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right)^n = e^k.$$
Is it possible to prove it using the other formula: $\lim(1+\frac 1 n)^n = e?$

EDIT:
I think I already got it:
$$(1+ \frac{k}{n})^n = (1+ \frac{1}{\frac{n}{k}})^{k \cdot \frac{n}{k}} \rightarrow e^k$$
Is this correct?

Comment: Why would you use this limit for your example? Your limit for $(n+1)/(n-2)$ is trivial.

Comment: There are many questions that have answers to this very question: [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/54499) shows that the series for $e^k$ equals this limit.

Comment: And also [$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(1+\frac{r}{n})^n$ is equal to ${e^{r}}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115863/lim-n-rightarrow-infty1-fracrnn-is-equal-to-er)

Comment: @Aemilius It's correct. See my post.

Answer (score 3):

Since $f(x)=x^k$ is a continuous function, we obtain:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1 +\frac k n\right)^n = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1 +\frac k n\right)^{\frac{n}{k}\cdot k } = \left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1 +\frac k n\right)^{\frac{n}{k} }\right)^k=e^k$$